# How to draw turing machine for a^p where p is a prime number?

Tags: primes, turing-machines

I dont know how to draw a turing machine for prime numbers. can anyone draw a diagram representing the above machine?

Answer (score -1):

1. Draw a Turing Machine for a^b where a and b are any two numbers.
2. Draw a Turing Machine for p where p is a prime number.
3. Combine drawing 1 and drawing 2.

Comment: How to draw turing machine for p where p is a prime number?

Comment: Draw a Turing machine for division and use trial division to see if a number is prime.  To solve a complex problem, break it up into simpler parts.